# buck converter feedback control

Tags: operational-amplifier, buck, control

This is a very classic problem
I am working on a buck converter using LTC7803 to charge a battery but to do that i need to make a relation of battery & Buck voltage for the feedback voltage (Vfb).

For example:
Battery range: 0.5v to 4.2v
Buck charging range: 1v to 4.7v (0.5v offset)

Vfb pin changes output between 0(max output) to 2.0v (cut off)

my goal is to design the control using op amps, if someone can help me design its control, i will be very grateful.

I will control the current and charging time by myself, just need help in designing control using op amps.

[image]

Comment: Please ask a specific question

Comment: @VoltageSpike need help in buck feedback control circuit design help which would compensate the output error vs required output.

Comment: It's time to study opamps then.

Comment: That is a broad question, please narrow it down to exactly what you need help with

Comment: yes sir @BrianDrummond i am reading about error amplifiers but i think to implement the solution i need to learn proper instrumentational amplifier? If you can give me a big hint like a sequence of which OP amps would do this thing, i will design it myself :)

Comment: My school was mainly focused on telecom and embedded engineering so i missed a lot about analog electronics

Comment: Sure give me something relative to read which would enhance my knowledge on the broadness of this question and i would come up with a narrow question ;) @VoltageSpike my main goal is to feed error voltage into Vfb which would result => Vbuck = VBat + 0.5v. so how to create correct error feedback voltage. i am reading error amplifier but im confused with these type I, II & III compensators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The LT7803 will try and regulate the voltage on the Vfb pin to 0.8V (in its regular running mode). That means if the voltage is lower on this pin it switch 'more' and allow more current to regulate the voltage up. You don't need a resistive divider to accomplish the feedback, you can insert anything you like (like a bunch of opamps, you could even turn this into an MPPT tracker, I've done that once before, or even a DAC an ADC so you could put software in the loop). But realize that you could create instabilities, and you will have to compensate the loop to keep it stable.

[image]
Source: https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ltc7803.pdf